# Python ImageIO Gif Set Delay Between Frames

Tags: python, image, numpy, gif

I am using ImageIO: https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userapi.html , and I want to know how to set delay between frames in a gif.

Here are the relevant parts of my code.

```
import imageio 
. . . 
imageio.mimsave(args.output + '.gif', ARR_ARR)
```

where `ARR_ARR` is an array of `numpy uint8` 2d array of couplets.

To be clear, I have no problem writing the gif. I cannot, however, find any clarification on being able to write the amount of delay between frames.

So, for example, I have frames 0 ... 9

They always play at the same rate. I would like to be able to control the number of milliseconds or whatever unit between frames being played.

Answer (score 7):

Found it using `imageio.help("GIF")` you would pass in something like

`imageio.mimsave(args.output + '.gif', ARR_ARR, fps=$FRAMESPERSECOND)`

And that seems to work.