# Speed up existing Gif with Imageio Python

Tags: python, gif, python-imageio

I am looking to speed up the gif I made with `Imageio` in python. I do not have the images that i used to make gif but I do have the gif.

I cannot find suitable source for this in `imageio` documentation or anywhere online. Can you suggest me something?

Answer (score 3):

This question is partially answered in [Python ImageIO Gif Set Delay Between Frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39581300/python-imageio-gif-set-delay-between-frames).

```
import imageio

gif_original = 'foo.gif'
gif_speed_up = 'foo2.gif'

gif = imageio.mimread(gif_original)

imageio.mimsave(gif_speed_up, gif, fps=$FRAMESPERSECOND)
```

See `imageio.help("GIF")` for further details.